# Running Watchdog inside a container to monitor attached directories

Tags: json, docker, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am attempting to run Watchdog from inside a Docker Container that has access to an external directory.  I want Watchdog to react to a certain class of files (*.json) when they are created within this directory tree.  I've attached the directory structure using the -v command and I can view the directory just fine.  However, the normal triggers like

> 'touch test.json'

don't seem to have any effect at all.   Any suggestions?